# Is it possible to somehow use pipes in kendo-editor in Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, src, angular-pipe, prose-mirror

Is it possible to somehow use pipes in kendo-editor in Angular?

My use case is the following. I have implemented the image uploading from local machine to my own endpoint (as described [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/editor/how-to/upload-integration/)) . Also, I have implemented a get endpoint which returns the image. So, I can use the links to retrieve images by the `src` image attribute. But I need user to be authenticated to call the get endpoint.

My research on the question: `How to intercept the src http request and set headers for it?` led me to a solution with the secure pipe, which would run the request for me. E.g. [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/loading-images-with-authorization-8aab33663ba6) article describes the solution.

I was able to implement the solution. So, now when in my Angular template I have:

```
<img [attr.src]="'http://localhost:44123/image/view/image280820208888.png' | authImage | async" />
```

The image is loaded through the endpoint, because I am able to use authentication (because I run the http request explicitly instead of delegating that to browser).

So, now it would be really very very great if I were able to somehow add the code

```
<img [attr.src]="'http://localhost:44123/image/view/image280820208888.png' | authImage | async" />
```

into the kendo editor value and actually see an image. But I can not figure out how can I use pipes inside the kendo editor`s value.

For the authentication I am using a header with a bearer token.

So, could someone suggest me an idea how I can use pipes inside the kendo editor?

The option to preload images and store them in the src of the kendo editor`s value as the base64 is not appropriate for me, because in my kendo editor`s values there might me a lot of images, and I store the value as a string in database. So, if I use the base64 I may run out of space quickly (because, I will store all the images in the text).

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l8gwnk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) is my attempt to use a directive. As one can see the class for the directive gets added to an image, but the alert message does not fire.

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: '.customDownload',
})
export class ImgHandlingDirective {
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>,
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    
    alert("code reached");
  }
}
```

Verification that the class was added to an image:

[image]

[Here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/editor/api/EditorComponent/) is the kendo-editor component api.

The directive itself works fine. If we add the `<img class="customDownload" />` into the template of app.component, then the code in directive will get reached and an alert will fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a directive, but the image will be uploaded twice, once natively and once via httpClient:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: 'img[src]',
})
export class ImgHandlingDirective {
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>,
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';

    const url = this.el.nativeElement.src;

    this.loadImage(url).subscribe(src => {
      this.el.nativeElement.src = src;
      this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    });
  }
  private loadImage(url: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http
      // load the image as a blob
      .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
        // create an object url of that blob that we can use in the src attribute
        map(e => URL.createObjectURL(e)),
      );
  }
}
```

**after update:**
you can change the `uploadImage()` function to upload it via `httpClient`

```
public uploadImage(): void {
  const { src } = this.imageInfo;

  this.http
  // load the image as a blob
  .get(src, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
    // create an object url of that blob that we can use in the src attribute
    map(e => URL.createObjectURL(e)),
  ).subscribe(() => {
    // Invoking the insertImage command of the Editor.
    this.editor.exec('insertImage', this.imageInfo);

    // Closing the Dialog.
    this.close();
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is possible to add a custom directive to the image somehow? So that not to upload in a custom way the images which are not in the kendo editor.

Comment: I just have tried out. The directive does not reach into the kendo-editor. :(

Comment: @SasukeUchiha create an example on stackblitz.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I just have updated y question.

Comment: You can reproduce the issue by uploading an image and seeing it in the editor content. Once the image is uploaded I need the directive to be called, but it does not get called.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I added another implementation

Comment: I need to achieve the same behavior. Could you, please, post a link to stackblitz with your solution working? Because from what I see right now the answer your provided is useless in solving the issue. The directive does not reach into the kendo-editor.

Comment: @Chris, thank you. But, `The option to preload images and store them in the src of the kendo editor\`s value as the base64 is not appropriate for me, because in my kendo editor\`s values there might me a lot of images, and I store the value as a string in database. So, if I use the base64 I may run out of space quickly (because, I will store all the images in the text).`

Comment: @ohidano give me an api to upload the image for testing so I can make an example on stackblitz

Comment: @Chris, I do not understand what do you need the api for? The issue here is that neither the pipes nor the directives are not called from inside the `kendo-editor` as I has demonstrated in the stackblitz in my question (for directive). Could you modify my example in the question in such a way so that the directive's alert message would be called?